# Waiting for RabbitMQ mandatory publish?

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, amqp, bunny

Using RabbitMQ with Bunny (Ruby), I'd like to publish and want to avoid losing messages if there are no queues consuming from a fanout exchange. From my library standpoint, I'm willing to wait for the return and give a clear answer to clients if the message was sent or not. Is putting a sleep in this the only way to achieve that?

```
def publish(topic, message_type, message, key = nil)
    ch = @conn.create_channel
    exchange = ch.fanout(topic, :durable => true, :auto_delete => false)

    sent = true
    exchange.on_return do |return_info, properties, content|
        sent = false
    end

    exchange.publish(message,
        :mandatory => true,
        :persistent => true,
        :type => message_type,
        :app_id => Emque::Producing.configuration.app_name,
        :content_type => "application/json")

    # Give message a chance to return if it can't be routed
    sleep 0.5

    ch.close
    return sent
end
```

Answer (score 0):

basic.return is an asynchronous operation in the protocol. You can use a synchronisation primitive (e.g. Bunny has Concurrent::Condition, since Ruby lacks anything distantly similar to java.util.concurrent) but what you really want is publisher confirms. See "When will messages be confirmed?" on http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html.